# $d$-Dimensional Brownian Motion Martingales

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, stochastic-integrals, brownian-motion

Let $d > 1$ and let $W_t$ denote a standard $d$-dimensional Brownian motion starting at $x\neq 0$. Let $M_t = \log|W_t|$ for $d = 2$, and $M_t= |W_t|^{2-d}$ for $d > 2$. Show that $M_t$ is a martingale.

Comment: @ user : Use Itô's lemma and look at the drift part and check that the diffusion part is ok for your process to be a martingale and not only a local martingale. Best regards

Answer (score 3):

On the contrary, these are classic examples of local martingales
that are **not** martingales.

1. **Exercise 2.13 (An important counterexample)** on page 194 of
   *Continuous Martingales and Brownian Motion (3rd edition)* by 
   Daniel Revuz and Marc Yor.
2. **Exercises 3.36 and 3.37** on page 168  of 
   *Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus (2nd edition)*
   by Ioannis Karatzas and Steven E. Shreve.